# Accessing user control from a page in another namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

my question seems simple but I couldnt find the solution.

I have an aspx as follows :

```
namespace WebApplication3.asp_x
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and an ascx as follows:

```
namespace WebApplication3.asc_x
{
    public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public LinkButton lbTest
        {
            get {
                return this.lbTest;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From the aspx file, I want to access the public property lbTest and I do the following but it doesnt work(it doesnt compile)

```
namespace WebApplication3.asp_x
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton lb = WebApplication3.asc_x.WebUserControl1.lbTest;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is missing here?

Comment: Please provide the compiler error message. It should tell you where the problem is.

Comment: Compiler says :Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WebApplication3.asc_x.WebUserControl1.lbTest.get'. Intellisense also does not suggest it. I just wrote it to express what kind of access I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a strange calling

```
LinkButton lb = WebApplication3.asc_x.WebUserControl1.lbTest;
```

Because you will need an instance to call it's label.

like if you have an instance of the `usercontrol` on the page only then you can call it's public property.

```
namespace WebApplication3.asp_x
{
   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        WebApplication3.asc_x.WebUserControl1 ob=new WebApplication3.asc_x.WebUserControl1();
        LinkButton lb = ob.lbTest;
      }
   }
}
```

### Edit 1

You need to first find the `placeholer` first
Then find the `user-control` in place hoder
then find the link button.

Suppose you have a place holder `p1` in your page
Find it as follows

```
PlaceHolder p=(PlaceHolder)Page.FindControl('p1');
```

Then find the user control inside place holder p as follow

Suppose you have user control `uc1` in the place holder.

```
UserContro1 uc1=(UserControl1)p.FindControl("uc1");
```

And then you can find the link inside this
As this

```
LinkButton lb = uc1.lbTest;
```

Comment: I know, but how can I create an instance of a user control?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is already right what you say. The thing is, that this question is a simplified version of the problem I have and in that real scenario, the user control is not directly in the aspx page, but it is in a placeholder and this placeholder is associated with the ascx through sitecore. Thats why I dont have the usercontrols instance in codebehind.

Comment: A follow up question. I need to register this LinkButton to a script manager update panel. But if I create an instance manually, like you offered, it would not work for the script manager because the instance is not the one that will be created in runtime on the page. Is it true?

Comment: You can use `findcontrol` I am updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the **ID of the usercontrol** to access any property. 
The given Id is actually the **usercontrol's instance name** in **codebehind**.

It's not a static property to access like WebApplication3.asc_x.WebUserControl1.lbTest

Comment: How can I see what the id of the instance is? I have the class but it has no id.

Comment: Are you using the user control in the Default Page?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is already right what you say. The thing is, that this question is a simplified version of the problem I have and in that real scenario, the user control is not directly in the aspx page, but it is in a placeholder and this placeholder is associated with the ascx through sitecore. Thats why I dont have the  usercontrols instance in codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to instantiate (make a new object of) the user-control).

Example:

```
LinkButton lb = (new WebApplication3.asc_x.WebUserControl1()).lbTest;
```

Or something like that.
Unless it is already a control on your page; then simply use the server ID.